# WPF: request server in button click event

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, threadpool

I am sending request to WCF service in button click event, each time when user click the button I am creating separate thread to get data from WCF service. So the question is when user click the button multiple times in short period I need to crate separate thread, but before I need to put all other threads in sleeping state, what is the best practice to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you disable the button after click till the thread querying WCF service returns?

Comment: i have such requirement, so i can't disable it

Comment: I am not sure but if you are using asynchronous calls (most of the cases) there is no point of sleeping other threads as request to the server has already been made. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BackgroundWorker class it can be achieved, recently I have answered this sort of question and example code can also be used from here:

[ComboBox items loaded event wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673673/combobox-items-loaded-event-wpf/4673792#4673792)